# Joining two tables using a third one

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm new in SQL and I'm struggling two join these two tables using the orders table.
The orders table has columns user_id, product_id as foreign keys. 
I've tried to do inner joins with union but I cannot get it right.

```
create table users(
id int not null unique,
name varchar(25) not null,
age int not null check (age >= 18),
email varchar(50) not null unique,
password varchar(100) not null,
primary key(id, email)
);

create table products(
id int not null,
product_name varchar(25) not null,
price money not null,
stock int not null,
primary key(id)
);

create table orders(
user_id int not null,
product_id int not null,
amount int not null,
foreign key(user_id) references users(id),
foreign key(user_id) references products(id)
);
```

Any help ?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Yep we're gonna need the fields you expect your query to return. And I'm not sure you're gonna need any union to do that.

Comment: BTW, no order_id needed?

Comment: You're also going to need order_line - unless in your industry one only has one product per order - v. unusual, no? Unless it's `nuclear_power_plant`?

Comment: I want to return username and the product which he buys using the orders table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.name, p.product_name, o.amount
from users u
left join orders o on  u.id = o.user_id
left join products p on o.product_id = p.id;
```

In this little [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0175a4a03d9362d68ba730478745795f) you can see that User1 has orderd product "Apple" and he orderd 5 peaces. User2 ordered 1 PC. Hope it helps.

You can also use aliases soyour final result looks better :)

```
select u.name "User name"
       , p.product_name "Product"
       , o.amount "Number of products ordered"
from users u
left join orders o on  u.id = o.user_id
left join products p on o.product_id = p.id;
```